Large library dependencies in github actions
I have a project in C++ that needs that all dependency libraries to be compiled as static libraries - think boost, libcurl, openssl etc - as well as a customized version of GCC.
These dependencies are currently being built under a docker for centos-7/8 prior to the project itself being compiled.
The size of the dependencies when compiled is 2.5 GiB.
The time to build all these dependencies on a 24 core machine is superior to one hour. For that reason obviously I would not want the dependencies to be built together with the project, every time there is a new pull request.
Is there a way to implement this in Github actions? What would be the recommended solution? Should I compile the dependencies externally and somehow push it to Github?

Github can trigger runners in self-hosted servers, meaning they will trigger the run in your pre-configured, on-premises servers. This way, you can set up your own library dependencies and link against them without taking space on GitHub servers.
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners
